# How to validate an email exists in an Active Directory forest

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to write a PowerShell script which validates whether a list of emails within a file are valid against the Active Directory forest. I have a script which works for my specific domain, but it doesn't find emails associated to other domains within the corporate forest.

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\path\emails.txt) {
    if(Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '$line'") {
        "$line is valid"
    }
    else {
        "$line is invalid"
    }
}
```

Result:

```
account1@domainA.com is valid
account2@domainA.com is valid
account3@domainB.com is invalid
```

Account3@domainB.com returns invalid because it's part of another domain, but I'd like it to return valid since it's part of the corporate forest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked. It takes elements of the proposed solutions and cycles through all the domain controllers. I would have preferred to leverage the Get-ADForest cmdlet in a way to prevent the need to specify DCs, but this suffices for the problem's purpose.

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\path\emails.txt) {
        foreach($DC in Get-Content C:\path\DCs.txt){
            if(Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '$line'" -Server $DC) {
                "$line FOUND in $DC"
                Add-Content -Path "C:\path\validemails.txt" -Value "$line : $DC"
                break
            }
            else {
                "$line not found in $DC"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the server (domain controller) for the other domains:

```
$DC = 'DC_name'
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\path\emails.txt) {
    if(Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '$line*'" -Server $DC ) {
        "$line is valid"
    }
    else {
        "$line is invalid"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Server` parameter, but specify the port `3268` since that is the port used for the global catalog. The global catalog is the listing for your whole forest.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '$line'" -Server domain.com:3268
```

Where `domain.com` is the DNS name of any domain in your forest.

Here are the various ports used for Active Directory:

- 389:  LDAP - single domain only (the default if you don't specify anything)
- 3268: Global Catalog - your whole forest
- 636:  LDAP over SSL
- 3269: Global Catalog over SSL